# How to view a full size image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

When there is scaling done via url, how can one view the original full size image?

As an example:

img.example.com/h2iFU3NCxKNS01seXA5JEZoGSGc=/fit-in/300x300/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/example-images/R-154518-8594076515-7987.jpeg.jpg

The image is scaled to 300x300 but true size is 1600x1600

We know "R-154518-8594076515-7987.jpg" is the true source, but how do we access the true source without the filters?

*Sorry if the tags I have used are not relevant to the question*

Comment: Read: [ask] and [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: It depends on the API on the site that is doing this. Is there any documentation?

Comment: As above, it greatly depends.  There is a clear url "parameter" in the path: `/300x300/` - you could try this with different values, eg `/1600x1600/` or maybe remove it completely.  Maybe remove or change the `/fit-in/` parameter which appears to be instruction how to scale.

Comment: @phuzi https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:images

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, I tried some variations, but unfortunately no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the site where you want to know the original img
Each site has its own way, and there are sites that are impossible to see the original img